# How do I decrease the slew rate of an op amp?

Tags: operational-amplifier, delay, slew-rate

I need to reduce the slew rate of a voltage follower, so that if I change the input signal from 0 to 5V, the output signal will rise progressively up to 5V in say, about 5 seconds, so a slew rate of 1V/s.

Comment: Integrators do this dV/dt=Ic/C where Ic is the inverting input V/R relative to reference Vin+

Comment: Do you hope something special behaviour if the input happens to be other than 0V or 5V, for ex. 2V or 3V? Should something cause Uout to drop? Do you expect Uout to stop or continue to rise to +Vcc if Uin stays at 5V?

Comment: @user287001 Not specifically, the only thing that should happen is that the output changes up or down to the input voltage at 1 V/s, so it should stop at 5V if Uin stays at 5V

Comment: Current-output opamps (CA3080, and the triple CA3060) can use both an Iset current and an output Capacitor, to control the SlewRate.

Comment: Do you want to do this while maintaining the small-signal bandwidth? If so, that is difficult question. If all you want is slow response to large, square-wave or pulse-like inputs, user287001 s answer seems OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This should work if you have plusminus 8...15V supplies for the opamps. The zener diodes limit the integrator input voltage to plusminus 6.8V. The integrator drifts towards Uin until it's reached. The drifting speed is 1V/s. This is not one percent exact due the tolerances of the parts. You may need a trimpot in the place of the 68kOhm resistor.

This is quite brutal control circuit and there's surely a short settling oscillation when the limit has been reached. Test or simulate , if it's small and short enough for you. If it's not good enough, a proper PD controller is needed.

Note: the polarity of the elko in the integrator allows only positive Uout. Negative Uout needs something else.

Answer (score 1):

If the 1V/s does not need to be exact you can even do with just 1 opamp.

Connect your input to the + input.
Connect a 1meg resistor to the output.
Connect the other end of the 1meg resistor to both the opamp - input, to a 100u cap and to your circuit output.
Connect the other end of the 100u cap to ground.

circuit output is where your requested output appears.

Make sure your opamp has supply voltage +-V that is much, say 10x, as large as your input. So if your input is between -1 and 1V, set the opamp powersupply to eg +-10V

The larger the difference between your input and the opamp power supply, the more linear the circuit behaves.

Also note that the circuit output is high R. You need to buffer it if your circuit output needs to be low R